# Spring using different contexts and SpringBeanAutowiringSupport in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have the following problem. My multi module spring application is loading up two different contexts at startup.

Context one is loaded up with this code snippet.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and the other one via the rest webservice

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/components_webservice.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now I got a jsp using this command to use autowired beans inside the jsp.

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

This only makes it possible to autowire the beans defined in the main context. I can't autowire beans from the REST Servlet declared context. Is there a way to make this context available inside the jsp? I know one way would be to declare all the beans inside the main context, but I want them to keep separated.

Greetings,
smoothny

Comment: Check the javadoc for ContextLoader here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html#getCurrentWebApplicationContext(). You might be able to configure the location using the "contextConfigLocation" param.

Answer (score 1):

Dont put any logic inside your jsp. Autowire fields in your controllers and pass generated values to the model.

Comment: It would not make a difference, because the controllers might run inside a different context too. My problem is how to autowire beans from another context (contextConfigLocation configured one vs the default spring context).

Comment: You may try to use the import tag, but that might lead to circular dependent contexts: <import resource="WEB-INF/components_webservice.xml`/>.